# Jquery slider issue after click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I'm Using Jquery slider function

```
function slideSwitchByNavigation(id) {
    clearInterval(t);
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');
    if ($active.length == 0)
        $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');
    var $next = $('#slideshow DIV.each_text').eq(id);
    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $active.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');

        $active.css('opacity', '0');
        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
    });
    slideNavigation($next.index());    
}
```

On this html element:

```
<div class="pagination" id="pagination" onmouseover="over()" onmouseout="out()" style="display: block;">
    <a class="" id="0" onclick="slideText($(this))"></a> 
    <a class="" id="1" onclick="slideText($(this))"></a> 
    <a class="" id="2" onclick="slideText($(this))"></a> 
    <a class="active" id="3" onclick="slideText($(this))"></a> 
</div>
```

Slidetext function

```
function slideText(element) {
    disableHref();
    clearInterval(t);

    if (element.attr('class') != 'active') {
        slideSwitchByNavigation(element.attr('id'));
        t = setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);


        // console.log(element.attr('id'));
    }
     setTimeout(function(){ enableHref(); }, 2000);
```

}

And I'm having weird issue, when i don't use bullets on div a list everything is ok, but when i click on a element to slide to this text slider is going crazy,  For examle now i have active element on id=3 and next will be element with id=0 , when i click element with id=2 slider will go to element 2 and will display element 0 in background . My question is How to reset counter and begin after click event for example slider goes normal from id0 to last id , and when i click one of numbers that item will go active and after that active element will be one after clicked element.

Thanks for your help 
Best Regards

Comment: ID's can't have such names. ID name must begin with letter...

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem? Also what is the function `slideText()`?

Comment: I will try to add jsfiddle but i think it's almost impossible because page is dynamicly from cms.

Comment: Please fix the grammar and formatting as it's impossible to understand what you are trying to say. Try to put an image explaining your requirement.